# Removing call from stack trace in python

Tags: python, recursion, stack-trace

I'm using a recursive function that doesn't directly call itself, but throught other private methods, for example:

```
def recur(x):
    # do something
    __a(x)

def __a(x):
    # do something
    __b(x)

def __b(x):
    if (something):
        recur(x-1)
```

Whenever an exception happens in "recur" the stacktrace prints all the calls of the private method "__a" and "__b".
This ia really redundent because these functions exist only for my writing choice, and it makes it harder to understand the trace.

How can I omit the calls of the inner methods from the traceback?

Comment: I do not encourage omitting info from the stack trace in python.  That said I'd suggest you take a look at [idlelib.run's implementation of trimming the stack trace](https://github.com/python-git/python/blob/master/Lib/idlelib/run.py#L163) as it has almost all the code you would need to implement your own version.

Comment: Why would you want to do this? Also, Python does not have "private" methods. Python is a consenting-adult language. The core reason your traceback is harder to understand is because you're trying to hide the functions. By altering the traceback, you're not helping anyone.

Comment: @sytech Creating the function "__a" and "__b" was just a random choice to make my code easier for me to write. I can just delete these functions and write everyting in "recur" and than the trace looks just as I want it.
Now the trace is 3 times longer for no reason for the person reading it.

Comment: +1 because this can be applied to function decorators which you don't want to pollute in the stacktrace.
My example is `@logExceptions` that simply logs an exception and raises it.